# In flutter, I'd like to download and play media just only inside the app not available in storage just like downloaded youtube videos

Tags: flutter, http, download, media-player, internals

I am using http, video player, audio service packages. Is there anyway to for my
flutter app to perform download and play video like you tube?

Comment: Hello @Htet have you found the solution ?

Comment: Not yet. I am still searching for a solution and currently learning Rails.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube application doesn't actually download the videos that it plays. It uses streaming in order to grab chunks of the video and bring them into the memory and play them on the go.

If you download any content in your Flutter application, there are two places you can store that content:

- In the memory
- In the storage space (usually NAND storage on modern mobile devices or HDD or SSD on desktops which Flutter also can run on)

So dependent on your situation, you might want to consider storing the content only in a buffer in the memory.

If you wish to store the content on disk and read it from there, there is a great package called [path provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) that you can grab from pub.dev and place in your application. This package helps with grabbing the location of for instance the documents directory on an Android or iOS device. The actual saving of the content can be done using Dart's IO functionality.

Comment: I am still confused with downloading and storing. If I downloaded the video will it be able to find in file manager without using path provider?